# Setting Time Picker throwing error SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I think this is a very famous issue but I went through couple of posts and I couldn't find the answer.
In my web page I have 3 RadTimePicker based on specific case I'm asking the user to insert the time only for 2 RadTimePickers and 1 is staying empty but I'm taking care of it in the DB I'm assigning it to a value.What can be the problem?????

```
Private m_TimeOfday As Date
Private m_FromTime As Date
Private m_ToTime As Date
   'TimeOfday
    Public Property TimeOfday() As Date
        Get
            Return m_TimeOfday
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            m_TimeOfday = value
        End Set
    End Property

   'FromTime
    Public Property FromTime() As Date
        Get
            Return m_FromTime
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            m_FromTime = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'ToTime
    Public Property ToTime() As Date
        Get
            Return m_ToTime
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            m_ToTime = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

aspx.code:

```
<telerik:RadTimePicker ID="rtpRuleTime" runat="server" Width="90px" Visible="true"></telerik:RadTimePicker>
                            From:&nbsp;<telerik:RadTimePicker ID="rdtpFrom" runat="server" Width="90px" Visible="true" ></telerik:RadTimePicker>
                            To:&nbsp;<telerik:RadTimePicker ID="rdtpTo" runat="server" Width="90px" Visible="true"></telerik:RadTimePicker>
```

VB.NET Code:

```
   If rcbRuleType.SelectedValue <> "3" Then
                '# Saving the RuleTime which been set int the table automatically to 23 PM
                Dim dt As DateTime = New DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0)
                rule.TimeOfday = dt
            Else
                '# Saving From Time - To Time
                Dim tsFrom As TimeSpan = rdtpFrom.SelectedTime()
                Dim dtFrom As String = New DateTime(1900, 1, 1, tsFrom.Hours, tsFrom.Minutes, 0)
                rule.FromTime = dtFrom

                '# Saving From Time - To Time
                Dim tsTo As TimeSpan = rdtpTo.SelectedTime()
                Dim dtTo As DateTime = New DateTime(1900, 1, 1, tsTo.Hours, tsTo.Minutes, 0)
                rule.FromTime = dtTo

            End If
```

Comment: Is it happenning for a particular date time you pick or for all values?

Comment: Where's the exception being thrown? In particular, which of the three is problematic when you leave it blank/null/empty-string/whatever, and exactly what is the default value here?